# Module in shinyApp not recognize by app.R

Tags: r, shiny, module

I want my shinyApp to be modularized.

For this I started with the basics, where I just have the basic `app.R` and a module `plot.R` to plot the data.

However, even though there is no error message, the module part is not correctly executed, as after selecting the data and executing the analysis no plot is obtained.

```
# Shiny
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjqui)
library(bslib)
library(shinybusy) # For busy spinners
library(shinyjs)

# Data
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

# Plots
library(ggplot2)

# Stats
library(stats)   #fisher.test, wilcox.test
library(effsize) #Cohen.d

# Sources
source("plot.R")


not_sel <- "Not Selected"

# User interface
ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "Plotter",
  windowTitle = "Plotter",
  tabPanel(
    useShinyjs(),
    title = "Plotter",
    titlePanel(""),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        title = "Inputs",
        fileInput("xlsx_input", "Select XLSX file to import", accept = c(".xlsx")),
        selectInput("num_var_1", "Variable X axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
        selectInput("num_var_2", "Variable Y axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
        actionButton("run_button", "Run Analysis", icon = icon("play"))
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel(
            title = "Plot",
            value = 1,
            
            # UI from the plot module
            plotUI("Plot1")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# Server

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  # Dynamic selection of the data
  data_input <- reactive({
    #req(input$xlsx_input)
    #inFile <- input$xlsx_input
    #read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
    iris
  })
  
  # We update the choices available for each of the variables
  observeEvent(data_input(),{
    choices <- c(not_sel, names(data_input()))
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_1", choices = choices)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_2", choices = choices)
  })
  
  num_var_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_1)
  num_var_2 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_2)
  
  
  # Server part of the love plot module
  plotServer("Plot1")
  
}


# Connection for the shinyApp
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

```
plotUI <- function(id, label="Plot") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    plotOutput("sel_graph")
  )
}
  
plotServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
      draw_boxplot <- function(data_input, num_var_1, num_var_2){
        
        if(num_var_1 != not_sel & num_var_2 != not_sel){
          ggplot(data = data_input, aes(x = .data[[num_var_1]], y = .data[[num_var_2]])) +
            geom_boxplot(fill = c("#16558F","#61B0B7","#B8E3FF")) + 
            theme_bw()
        }
      }
      
      ## BoxPlot -------------------------------------------------------------------
      
      plot_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button,{
        req(data_input())
        draw_boxplot(data_input(), num_var_1(), num_var_2())
      })
      
      
      output$sel_graph <- renderPlot(
        plot_1()
      )
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Try `plotOutput(ns("sel_graph"))`, as you are missing `ns` (namespace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue was that the module couldn't find `input$run_button` because it has a different namespace. What we need is a way to communicate with the module, that is, passing additional arguments to the module call.

Note: The fill argument passed to ggplot inside the module will provoke that the plot only work for Species variable.

App code:

```
# Shiny
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjqui)
library(bslib)
library(shinybusy) # For busy spinners
library(shinyjs)

# Data
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

# Plots
library(ggplot2)

# Stats
library(stats) # fisher.test, wilcox.test
library(effsize) # Cohen.d

# Sources
# source("plot.R")

plotUI <- function(id, label = "Plot") {
  tagList(
    plotOutput(NS(id, "sel_graph"))
  )
}

plotServer <- function(id, data, num_var_1, num_var_2, bttn) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observe(print(num_var_1()))


    plot_1 <- eventReactive(bttn(), {
      req(data())
      if (isolate(num_var_1()) != not_sel & isolate(num_var_2()) != not_sel) {
        ggplot(data = data(), aes(x = get(isolate(num_var_1())), y = get(isolate(num_var_2())))) +
          geom_boxplot(fill = c("#16558F", "#61B0B7", "#B8E3FF")) +
          theme_bw()
      }
    })

    ## BoxPlot -------------------------------------------------------------------



    output$sel_graph <- renderPlot(
      plot_1()
    )
  })
}

not_sel <- "Not Selected"

# User interface
ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "Plotter",
  windowTitle = "Plotter",
  tabPanel(
    useShinyjs(),
    title = "Plotter",
    titlePanel(""),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        title = "Inputs",
        fileInput("xlsx_input", "Select XLSX file to import", accept = c(".xlsx")),
        selectInput("num_var_1", "Variable X axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
        selectInput("num_var_2", "Variable Y axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
        actionButton("run_button", "Run Analysis", icon = icon("play"))
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel(
            title = "Plot",
            value = 1,

            # UI from the plot module
            plotUI("Plot1")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# Server

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Dynamic selection of the data
  data_input <- reactive({
    # req(input$xlsx_input)
    # inFile <- input$xlsx_input
    # read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
    iris
  })

  # We update the choices available for each of the variables
  observeEvent(data_input(), {
    choices <- c(not_sel, names(data_input()))
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_1", choices = choices)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_2", choices = select(data_input(), where(is.factor)) %>% names())
  })

  num_var_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_1)
  num_var_2 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_2)


  # Server part of the love plot module
  plotServer("Plot1", data_input, reactive(input$num_var_1), reactive(input$num_var_2), reactive(input$run_button))
}


# Connection for the shinyApp
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]